# Javascript parse query

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm having trouble with the following query. I'm pretty sure all the keys are right but the query isn't returning any objects. The problem line is:

```
query.equalTo("author", Parse.User.current());
```

If I take that line out then it returns me a random user's object, but I want this user's object. if I leave that line in I get no objects.

```
var query = new Parse.Query("personalInfoObject");
console.log(Parse.User.current().getUsername());
query.equalTo("author", Parse.User.current());
query.find({
success: function(results) {
    // results is an array of Parse.Object
    var obj=results[0];
    console.log(obj)

},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User` looks like a complex object.  If `author` is a simple string, that comparison won't find anything.  I see that you're printing out the `username` to the log, perhaps that's what you want to use  for the `where` clause.  It's hard to know without the structure of the objects.

Comment: It isn't an equal to in that sense, the docs say: equalTo(key, value)
Add a constraint to the query that requires a particular key's value to be equal to the provided value.

Comment: If `User` is a complex object, I think it would use the string representation of it for comparison.  It's not clear to me what that would be - it might be simply `[Object object]` - that's the "value" you'd be comparing `author` to.  I'd try using that part of the current user object that corresponds to the `author`  property in `personalInfoObject`.

Comment: @tvanfossen you were correct i made an error with my data scheme.